# SharpDX: What is the right approach to get smooth meshes without editing the model

Tags: c#, directx, shader, mesh, sharpdx

I'm loading obj files in c#-SharpDX. Everything works fine, i get the meshes with the assigned materials but the meshes are not really smooth:

[image]

Like i mentioned in the topic, i do not want to edit the mesh in an external tool.
I think i should edit my shader, but i am not really sure. is there maybe some option in sharpdx to make meshes smooth or something like that.
Also i tried, like i already said, to edit my shader but it was effortless.
Maybe someone can push me in the right direction. 
This is the shadercode with normal mapping:

```
cbuffer data :register(b0)
{
    float4x4 world;
    float4x4 worldViewProj;
    float4 lightDirection;
    float4 viewDirection;
    float bias;
};

struct VS_IN
{
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
    float3 tangent: TANGENT;
    float3 binormal: BINORMAL;
    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD;
};

struct PS_IN
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
    float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD;
    float3 lightDirection:LIGHT;
    float3 viewDirection:VIEW;
};

//texture
Texture2D textureMap:register(t0);
Texture2D normalMap:register(t1);
SamplerState textureSampler;

PS_IN VS( VS_IN input)
{
    PS_IN output = (PS_IN)0;

    float3 B=mul(world,input.binormal);
    float3 T=mul(world,input.tangent);
    float3 N=mul(world,input.normal);

    output.position = mul(worldViewProj,input.position);
    output.normal=N;
    output.texcoord=input.texcoord;



    float3x3 Tangent={T,B,N};
    output.lightDirection=mul(Tangent,lightDirection.xyz);
    output.viewDirection= mul(Tangent,viewDirection.xyz);

    return output;
}

float4 PS( PS_IN input ) : SV_Target
{
    float2 parallax=input.viewDirection.xy * normalMap.Sample( textureSampler, input.texcoord).a*bias;

    float4 D=textureMap.Sample( textureSampler, input.texcoord +parallax);
    float4 N=normalMap.Sample( textureSampler, input.texcoord +parallax)*2.0f-1.0f;

    return saturate(dot(N,input.lightDirection))*D+0.2F;
}
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at Catmull-Clark's or loop subvidision algorithms (the first one is to be used with quad meshes, the second one with triangle meshes). If you are using DirectX 11, you can also have a look at using the tesselation stage of your GPU to do this kind of stuff.

Comment: How are you loading your model? I assume you just want smoothed normals aka [gouraud shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gouraud_shading) ?

Comment: I think the gouraud shading is the right direction. i am currently tying it out but not getting good results. :( I try to use a shader without normal reflections. but the result is just bad.
I updated the shadercode above to my new shader. maybe someone has an idea what i am doing wrong.